# Sync Chaindata of Geth with Ethereum Wallet / Mist

Tags: blockchain

I have downloaded the blockchain via geth on my mac terminal. When i download the ethereum wallet, I find that it downloads the chain data again. Is there a way to get the ethereum wallet to use the chaindata already downloaded via geth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run geth before ethereum wallet  (it will connect to geth)

Comment: Thanks. I ran geth first and then opened Mist. It connected to geth.